# Magento2 : How to create frontend layout files for controller's different action wise?

Tags: magento2, layout, controllers

I have two controller action **[1]** `/app/code/Mycustom/Custompage/Controller/Mypage/View.php` and **[2]** 
`/app/code/Mycustom/Custompage/Controller/Mypage/View/Mytest.php` .

I have cretead frontend layout file named `selectpage_mypage_view.xml` and it's working proper for both controller action but i want to call different layout files for both controller. For second controller action i have created layout file named `selectpage_mypage_view_mytest.xml` but no luck. Any help should be appriciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have the name of the  layout correctly, look for the error elsewhere, for example in the namespace of the second controller.

Comment: @Raj find the answer below https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/255327/52244 hope this will help you, if it match your expectation please mark  it valid answer so it will useful others

Comment: @Raj, hope you got solution, if below given answer match your expectation please mark as valid answer so if someone looking for same they can use as their reference. any further help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add `subfolder` Controller, you should have this path :

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Controlerfolder/Controllername.php** => YES

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Controlerfolder/ControlerSubfolder/Controllername.php** => NO

SO in your case :

```
app/code/Mycustom/Custompage/Controller/Mypage/View.php // OK

app/code/Mycustom/Custompage/Controller/Mypage/Mytest.php // OK

app/code/Mycustom/Custompage/Controller/Mypage/View/Mytest.php // KO
```

Comment: Hi @PRINCE. So declaring controller in sub-folder is wrong way in M2?

Comment: I think so, I struggled once during hours to understand why it does not work, and I don't have an explanation for that, but it doesn't work with a subfolder.

Comment: @PRINCE please check magento compare page logic that support subfolder logic. and see the below given answer which might clear your doubt. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/255327/52244 any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As per asked quetion **[1]** & **[2]**, keeping same points in mind and giving real example.

In magento 2 **we can create sub-folder under controller  folder** and in that we can create custom controller as well as per our need.

**[1]** related to product detail page

```
/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Product/View.php
```

so it's access in frontend using url like `/catalog/product/view` (**it detail page so if access need to pass id value as param**)

example : `catalog/product/view/id/2`

and **default Layout Handles** for this page is `catalog_product_view`

**[2]** relate to  **magento's compare page**

```
/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Product/Compare/Index.php
```

so it's access in frontend using url like **`/catalog/product_compare/index`** (**sub-folder will merge with _** )

**So My Opinion : sub-folder controller access path will be like**

> FRONTNAME / folder (if sub-folders then merge with _) / Controller Name

and **default Layout Handles for this page is** `catalog_product_compare_index`